# Is your appearance as the game progresses linked to your performance?

Tags: batman-arkham-asylum

I'm currently playing through Arkham Asylum and having quite a blast.

As I'm playing I've noticed that Batman looks increasingly worse as the game progresses, which is no surprise considering all the punishment he has to endure. What I was wondering, however, is if this degradation is in any way related to your in-game performance, or if it is just a matter of how far along into the game you are (while some damage to your suit seems directly related to things that happen in cut-scenes, I also get beat up quite a bit from time to time).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've seen a number of different walk throughs (plus my own game) and I've never seen a difference in the way Batman looks at a given point in the story.

Based on a number of youtube videos I'd have to say that the answer is: No.

Comment: I agree. It doesn't seem to be linked to how you play and what you do but more related to the story and cutscenes.

Answer (score 8):

The damage to his cape and mask appear as you progress in the story, unrelated to your performance. The same applies to the stubble that grows overnight in Bruce Wayne's face.

Answer (score 3):

During certain cut scenes Batman sustains injuries that alter his appearence. These aren't avoidable unfortunately. To be honest though it makes him look really cool anyway. ;)